# IF statement not evaluating as true

Tags: nxbre

```
<xBusinessRules xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xBusinessRules.xsd">

<ObjectLookup id="Applicant" objectId="Args" member="Applicant"/>
<ObjectLookup id="CustomValues" objectId="Applicant" member="CustomValues"/>
<ObjectLookup id="ValidationErrors" objectId="Args" member="ValidationErrors"/>
<Boolean id="IsValid" value="True"/>

<ForEach id="CustomField" valueId="CustomValues">
    <ObjectLookup id="Field" objectId="CustomField" member="Field"/>
    <ObjectLookup id="CustomFieldName" objectId="Field" member="Key"/>
    <ObjectLookup id="CustomFieldValue" objectId="CustomField" member="Value"/>
    <Logic>

        <If>      
            <And>   
                <Equals leftId="CustomFieldName" rightId="XAGENTNAME">          
                </Equals>                   
            </And>       
            <Do>
                <Modify id="IsValid" value="False" type="Boolean"/>
                <ObjectLookup objectId="ValidationErrors" member="Add">
                    <Argument value="Custom_XAGENTNAME" type="String"/>
                    <Argument value="Pick a sales broker plz" type="String"/>
                </ObjectLookup>  
            </Do>         
        </If>
    </Logic>
</ForEach>
```

I have ran a        `rulesEngine.RuleContext.GetResult("CustomFieldName").Result` and it does equal to `XAGENTNAME` but won't set the `isValid` variable to false.

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Equals`, you are using a value with ID `XAGENTNAME` but you do not declare it.

Try with:

```
<Equals leftId="CustomFieldName" rightId="XAGENTNAME">
    <String id="XAGENTNAME" value="XAGENTNAME" />
</Equal>
```

Comment: yeah I didn't know it's means it's a variable. Is there a way you can tell NXBRE it's a string literal?

Comment: No, rules works by reference only. It's common practice to assert this kind of constants at the beginning of a rule file, like here: https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE/blob/master/NxBRE3/Rulefiles/test.xbre#L26-L37